# Rust error :Cannot return value referencing temporary value

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a code that returns the mode of a list of given numbers.
Here's the code :

```
 use std::collections::HashMap;

 fn mode (vector: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<&&i32> {
    let mut occurrences = HashMap::new();
    let mut n= Vec::new(); 
    let mut mode = Vec::new(); 

    for i in vector {
    let j= occurrences.entry(i).or_insert(0); 
        *j+=1;
    }

    for (num, occ) in occurrences.clone().iter() {

        if occ> n[0] {
            n.clear();
            mode.clear();

            n.push(occ);
            mode.push(num);
        } else if occ== n[0] {
                mode.push(num);             
            }
        }

    mode
}

fn main () {
    let mut numbers: Vec<i32>= vec![1,5,2,2,5,3];    // 2 and 5 are the mode
    numbers.sort();
    

    println!("the mode is {:?}:", mode(&numbers));
}
```

I used a vector for the mode since a dataset could be multimodal.
Anyway, I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
 --> src/main.rs:26:5
  |
13 |     for (num, occ) in occurrences.clone().iter() {
  |                       ------------------- temporary value created here
...
26 |     mode
  |     ^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Comment: I think there are an issue in your algo `thread 'main' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 0 but the index is 0'` [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=065c97cd2007de77cd5b0e31c2f0dad6)

Comment: And i m not sure to understand what mode must do and what mode must return

Comment: Is it a requirement that `mode` return `Vec<&&i32>`? Could this be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return from the current function, any owned values are destroyed (other than the ones being returned from the function), and any data referencing that destroyed data therefore cannot be returned, e.g.:

```rust
fn example() -> &str {
  let s = String::from("hello");  // owned data
  &s  // error: returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

  // you can imagine this is added by the compiler
  drop(s);
}
```

The issue you have comes from `iter()`. `iter()` returns an iterator of shared references:

```rust
let values: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
for i in values.iter() {
  // i is a &i32
}

for i in values {
  // i is an i32
}
```

So when you call `occurrences.clone().iter()` you're creating a temporary value (via `clone()`) which is owned by the current function, then iterating over that data via shared reference. When you destructure the tuple in `(num, occ)`, these are also shared references.

Because you later call `mode.push(num)`, Rust realizes that `mode` has the type `Vec<&i32>`. However, there is an implicit lifetime here. The lifetime of `num` is essentially the lifetime of the current function (let's call that `'a`), so the full type of `mode` is `Vec<&'a i32>`.

Because of that, you can't return it from the current function.

### To fix

Removing `iter()` should work, since then you will be iterating over owned values. You might also find that you can remove `.clone()` too, I haven't looked too closely but it seems like it's redundant.

A couple of other points while you're here:

- It's rare to interact with `&Vec<Foo>`, instead it's much more usual to use *slices*: `&[Foo]`. They're more general, and in almost all cases more performant (you can still pass your data in like: `&numbers`)
- Check out clippy, it has a bunch of linter rules that can catch a bunch of errors much earlier, and usually does a good job explaining them: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy

Comment: I also had to change the 5th line with `let mut n= vec![0]; ` since i was trying to index an empty vector.
As @Vaillant Etienne suggested